# What is this circuits output and how can I simplify it?

Tags: logic-gates, boolean-algebra

I am doing a short module in Boolean Algebra we have covered gates and truth tables, I am doing a sample exam paper as practice but cannot understand how to do this logic gate question.

I need to do the following:

1. Find out what each gate is outputting
2. Use Boolean algebra to simplify the gate structure

If I understand this example I think I should be able to do another question. Can anyone help me?

[image: Diagram]

Comment: So what don't you understand?

Comment: What is each gate outputting as we progress, how can we make a simpler circuit to do the same thing?

Comment: On that drawing, write the formula for the logic that makes that output true... eg. first gate A, gate under that, AB etc. You will end up with F= something. Then simplify the something with algebra.

Answer (score 3):

What you should do is write down a truth table. For every state in the truth table, analyze every gate and work your way to the output. You can include this in the truth table - give the gates a name, and their own collum.

```
A B C | Ga1 Ga2 Ga3 | OUT
0 0 0 |  1   0   1  |  0
0 0 1 |  0   1   0  |  1
0 1 0 | ...
0 1 1 | ...
1 0 0 |
1 0 1 | 
1 1 0 |
1 1 1 |
```

EDIT: This is perhaps not the best way to do it here.
We can view every gate as a equation - the basic building blocks have quite simple equations: AND multiplies, OR Adds.

In this case, let's name every intermediate node. We can then look at the equation from an intermediate node to it's inputs. This will end up giving us an equation we can then simplify.

I prefer not to solve your specific example - let me build another so we can study this, and you can then apply this method to the exam question. Take the following:
[image: Simple circuit]

I named the intermediate nodes \$Y_{1}\$ and \$Y_{2}\$.

Now we can see that:

$$ Y_{1} = A \cdot B $$
$$ Y_{2} = B + C $$

and that the output \$Y\$
$$Y = Y_{1} \cdot Y_{2} $$
$$ \Leftrightarrow Y = (A \cdot B) \cdot (B + C) $$

Now you can use boolean algebra to simplify this and see if you can come to a simpler equation, perhaps provided some constraints. Let me give it a try and see how we can build our circuit with less gates, using only 2-input gates:

$$Y = (A \cdot B) \cdot (B + C) = A \cdot B \cdot B + A \cdot B \cdot C = A \cdot B$$

Obvioulsy this was a very simple example, but we see that we can build the same logic diagram by using just one gate!

[image]

I hope this is enought to get you started!

Thanks Trevor for pointing out a (silly) mistake on my part in the first version.

Comment: That is a good way to do it, but it doesn't really answer the exam question.

Comment: The only problem is that I don't know what the gates are outputting, does the first AND gate have only one input or is A inputting into both inputs? Does B have A input and then no other input?

Comment: @Ninja2k output of first gate is A and A so its just A. Yu can write that on the drawing. Do similar for the other gates, eg. 2nd gate = A.B, etc and you will have the final equation at the output. Then use logic algebra to simplify the equation.

Comment: I was careless and didn't fully read the question, my bad. This could be used, but would be clumsy - you could extract a boolean equation from the truth table and simplify that. 
Instead, you can also work your way form left to right, writing equations for every gate. I'll add this to my answer

Comment: +1 for good answer and koodos for not solving the original  logic. Good man.

Comment: Though your final logic isn't right.... Me thinks it's Y = A.B

Comment: You are right. It's been years since I've done boolean algebra. LEt me fix it.

Comment: yup u need Y=ABB + ABC = AB + ABC = AB(True + C) = AB